# ¿Como ejecuto un script a partir de tkinter sin que la ventana se crashee?

Tags: python

Estoy creando un programa, pero para que no se tenga que ejecutar ese programa dandole doble-click, estoy creando una app en tkinter que se encargara de eso.
El problema es que, cuando ejecuto el programa a partir del boton, este se ejecuta, pero la ventana de tkinter se cuelga y jamas vuelve a responder

Comment: Hola! Veo que sugeriste una edición (https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/127816) diciendo _La etiqueta python no debe usarse con la etiqueta python-3.x_. ¿Por qué? Precisamente estamos debatiendo al respecto en [Añadamos \[python\] a todas las preguntas de Python](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3746/83), ¿podrías exponer tu punto de vista allí para que no haya dos secciones de la comunidad yendo a contracorriente una de la otra? A mí me parece altamente útil que se usan ambas etiquetas, una por genérica y la otra cuando es algo específico de una versión.

Comment: la etiqueta python 3.x se usa para preguntas especificas de python 3. Ademas, este no es el lugar para decirme eso

Comment: Te lo comento por aquí porque en Meta no has participado. El uso es el que decida la comunidad y parece que hay bastante unanimidad en usar Python siempre, además de otra cuando sea necesario

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tkinter incorpora (por debajo, invisible para nosotros) un bucle de eventos que es quien detecta las acciones del usuario (si ha clicado el ratón por ejemplo) e invoca las funciones apropiadas dentro de tu código para manejar el evento.

Cuando el usuario clica un botón, el bucle de eventos lo detecta y llama a la función adecuada para manejar el evento. *Hasta que esa función no retorna, el bucle no puede procesar más eventos*. Cuando la función retorne, el bucle de eventos se reanuda y podrá seguir procesando acciones del usuario.

Por tanto si la función que atiende a un botón tarda mucho en retornar, entretanto la aplicación parecerá "colgada". Simplemente en ella el bucle de eventos está esperando el retorno de esa función y no puede atender acciones del usuario. El propio sistema operativo puede "pensar" también que la aplicación se ha colgado, pues el operativo le envía eventos de tipo "¿sigues vivo?" de vez en cuando para ver si responde a ellos (el bucle de eventos lo hace automáticamente). Si el bucle de eventos está parado no responderá a ellos y el operativo puede llegar a mostrar un diálogo del tipo "Parece que esta aplicación ha dejado de responder" y cerrarla.

A falta de ver tu código, sospecho que tu función no retorna nunca, pues hará algo del estilo de `sys.command()` para invocar ese otro programa que dices que querías lanzar, y mientras ese otro programa no retorne, tu función tampoco lo hará y el bucle de eventos estará congelado.

La solución es lanzar ese comando en otro proceso (usando la biblioteca python `subprocess`) o en otro hilo (usando `threads`), o usar una de más alto nivel como `concurrent.futures` que se ocupe de gestionar procesos o hilos como necesites.

No puedo darte más detalles sin saber con más precisión qué es lo que intentas hacer y sin ver parte de tu código.